# Acoustic phonons & Debye model, optical phonons & Einstein model

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, phonons

In our class today we spoke about the Einstein and Debye models. We associated the Einstein model with the optical phonons and the Debye one with the acoustic phonons. But I have a question:

what is the argument made for associating acoustic phonons with the Debye model and the optical phonons with the Einstein model?

Comment: Recall that acoustic phonons can have very low energy (as $k$ goes to zero), while optical phonons have a not-very-low energy even at $k=0$.

Comment: Yes I am aware. But what is the correlation between low energy and the debye model and high energy and the einstein model? Is it because the Einstein model is more accurate as the temperature increases, which implies higher energy in the crystal, while the debye shows good accuracy for low temperature values, which implies low energies in the crystal and therefore we associate it with modes that correspond to these low energies, which are the ones with low wavevector number aka the acoustic phonons?

Comment: No, it is just about the assumptions thrown into the derivations. Einstein assumed that there is only one phonon energy, and that looks closer to how optical phonon bands look, and is completely wrong for acoustic bands. Debye, prior to Einstein, covered the acoustic bands better, but did it classically, i.e. without quantum statistics. After Debye's model was fixed, it covers the low temperature part correctly.